# Android drawable folders system

Tags: android, drawable

so, I've created a project where I use an image in the action bar, but android only scaled it to the folders -mdpi, -hdpi, -xhdpi, -xxhdpi, why isn't it scaling to the low density folder ?

Btw, what if I want to use an image that is going to be the same size no matter what screen resolution is being used, should I create a folder just for this images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they removed ldpi because there are so few ldpi devices out and they can make use of mdpi anyway.

Having an image the same size on any resolution is what these folders are for!! If you put an image in the static drawable folder its size will be different depending on what device you use because the pixel density is the same in the picture but it has to be scaled differently on screen to adjust for the larger or smaller density of the screen

go read the introductory android tutorials to learn more about screen density

Comment: Thanks :) .. 
In relation to my second question, that was not what I wanted to ask, sorry.. I know that, but I have an image that is bigger than the maximum size set to the xxhdpi folder, and I want it in that size, but if I put the image in any drawable folder, it will be scaled, and when I scale it back with minHeight and minWidth in the layout xml file, it gets blurred...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. if you put a say 10x10px image in mdpi you need a 15px for hdpi and so forth. It probably gets blurred either because you try to scale up an image or the image is too heavy and can't allocate enough memory(this should crash the app though)

Comment: yes, I'm scaling up the image with minWidth and minHeight because the maximum density folder (xxhdpi) sets an image with 144px x 144px, but I want my image to be even bigger than that ... But as the image was scaled to 144x144, it gets blurred when I scale up in the xml file, I want to know how can I avoid this ? (sorry my english, I'm Portuguese).

Comment: What device are you using that uses the xxhdpi folder? I haven't used any yet. To see where your resources are taken from you can have different images in different folders but with the same name.  But if your question is why your picture gets blurry when it's upscaled, it's because of pixelation. A small image that looks good in 15x15 px will not look good if you just set it too 75x75px

Comment: I'm not using any, this folder was created automatically.. I've set the action bar logo and the image was scaled in every folder, in the xxhdpi folder it was scaled to 144x144.. I just want to use an independent image that don't scale from screen to screen, I want it fixed size and bigger than 144x144.. And I will explain better, I want it in this conditions because it's going to be displayed alone in a welcome activity, so I want it bigger to make the activity less empty..

Comment: So, should I put this image in an independent folder so it will not scale automatically from screen to screen or what stratagy should I follow ? this is my question

Comment: Ok so I'm assuming this is the automatically created icon that you want to appear bigger. 144 pixels is not much. If you scale it up it's going to get blurry, you need to create a larger image. You can't use a small image, scale it up and make it look good. put your phone against your computer, work from mdpi and up (mdpi is basically 72dpi like your monitor) hdpi should be 1.5 times larger than mdpi and xhdpi 1.75 times larger. Don't just scale it up, pixels don't handle upscaling very well. This should be an accepted answer. And you should still read the introductory screen density tutorials

Comment: if you put it in resources/drawable it will not take screen size into account thus making your image seem smaller/larger depending on what phone you use, if you put it in qualified folders /drawable-xhdpi and so on then you will be able to maintain aspect ratio but you **have**  to scale the image to different sizes like I just explained

Comment: Of course I will accept your answer, but I think I still didn't explain me very well.. The image i'm talking about is not the action bar logo, I just mentioned it so you can understand how I figured out that the maximum drawable density folder set the images to 144x144 px ...

Comment: the situation is, I have an image to be displayed in an activity, but this image has to be fixed size... so I can't put it in any drawable folder, because android take the images inside that folder and scale them automatically to different resolutions ... I don't want that, so where I put my image, in a folder created by me ?

Comment: you put it in the drawable folder without qualifiers **/res/drawable**  but you can't stretch it because it will get blurry.

Comment: Oh.. Eclipse is not creating that "default drawable" folder in my projects, I didn't know of it's existence.. I will create it manually. Thank's for your time, I'm new at android :) .

Comment: no problem, check out http://www.vogella.com , he has some great beginner tutorials